# SonarQube - A "NullPointerException" could be thrown;

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube reports this bug to me: `A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "getBody()" can return null.`

This is the code:

```
if (holdingResponseEntity == null || holdingResponseEntity.getBody() == null || holdingResponseEntity.getBody().getError() || holdingResponseEntity.getBody().getResult() == null) { throw new HoldingNotFoundException("Holding whit id=" + idHolding + " not found-"); }
```

Answer (score 8):

You first test if `getBody()` returns `null`.

SonarQube sees that and thinks the method can return null.

Then, you call the same method again. SonarQube just knows that the method can return null so it tells you the warning.

In other words, SonarQube thinks that it could return something different than `null` the first time but return `null` the second time.

If the method is just a simple getter and the object is not modified concurrently, this is no problem.

In order to remove the warning, you can do one of the following:

- Save the result of `getBody()` to a variable, check if it is null and continue if it is not
- Add a `//NOSONAR` comment telling SonarQube that you know what you are doing.

Note that you might want to explain why this is ok in the comment, if you decide for the second case.

Answer (score 4):

It could theoretically be the case that a repeated call of `getBody()` might return an other value. The following utilizes `hasBody()` and calls `getBody()` only once.

```
if (holdingResponseEntity == null
        || !holdingResponseEntity.hasBody()) {
    throw new HoldingNotFoundException("Holding with id=" + idHolding + " not found.");
}
T body = holdingResponseEntity.getBody(); // Change T appropriately.
if (body.getError() || body.getResult() == null) {
    throw new HoldingNotFoundException("Holding with id=" + idHolding + " not found.");
}
```

Normally you should check the source code of the library `getBody`. My guess: it is not a simple getter, but construes the body once. Because there is a `hasBody`.

Such things make code checkers valuable.

Answer (score 2):

However there are other ways to solve this as well, as answered above but if I want to solve it the way you have written the code with minimum changes and avoid warning from Sonar, this would be as below -

Using && operator will make sure once the condition fails , it would not check for subsequent condition , and that solves the issue .

```
if(holdingResponseEntity != null &&
                holdingResponseEntity.getBody() != null &&
                holdingResponseEntity.getBody().getError() != null &&
                holdingResponseEntity.getBody().getResult() != null){
           //Everything is good if it comes here

        }else{
            System.out.println("Going to throw ***** ");
            throw new HoldingNotFoundException("Holding whit id=" + idHolding + " not found-");
        }
```

Comment: If i understand correctly, your code still got a warning from SonarQube. Take a look at `holdingResponseEntity.getBody() != null` and `holdingResponseEntity.getBody().getError() !=null`. The first one is oke but the second one can throw NPE because the second one call `getBody()` again, and result can be null in theory. Unless you're checking like this `(body=holdingResponseEntity.getBody()) != null && body.getError() != null`

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way to solve this but in some of the scenario sonar will fail to check the condition so better you can use Optional to check null and sonar issue will be resolved
For Example:

> Optional.ofNullable(responseEntity.getBody()).isEmpty()

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that `holdingResponseEntity.getBody()` is returning `HoldingResponse`;

```
HoldingResponse holdingResponse = holdingResponseEntity.getBody();
if (null!=holdingResponse && null!=holdingResponse.getErrors()) {
    throw new HoldingNotFoundException("Holding whit id=" + idHolding + " not found-");
}
```

For more details check this https://community.sonarsource.com/t/false-positive-a-nullpointerexception-could-be-thrown/47025/3